# Hive transform query runs slow with ORC file

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, orc

We use python scripts to process data, and TRANSFORM to use them with hive.
I made two identical tables. First stores data in ORC, second one in TEXT.
Mappers for data, stored in ORC run x10 slower than for data stored in TEXT.

1) We use default ORC settings.

2) Query:

```
use db1;

set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=false;
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled=false;
set hive.execution.engine=tez;

ADD FILE /home/user/manage.py;
ADD FILE /home/user/cluster.mod;
ADD FILE /home/user/hive_serde.so;

ALTER TABLE aggregates ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (dt='${hiveconf:HIVE_CALC_DT}');

FROM (
  FROM visits
  MAP logins, geo_id, ua, os, device, version, splits, entrance_utm,
  is_bounce_visit, is_new_visit, screen, browser, um, ts_start, ts_end,
  ruid, project_id, geo_parents, custom_vars, page_views, totals
  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  USING 'python2.7 manage.py metrics_from_visits'
  AS project_id, splits, message_type, message
  WHERE dt = '${hiveconf:HIVE_CALC_DT}'
  CLUSTER BY project_id, splits, message_type) map_output

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE aggregates partition (dt='${hiveconf:HIVE_CALC_DT}')

REDUCE *
  USING 'python2.7 manage.py generate_aggregates --date ${hiveconf:HIVE_CALC_DT}'
  AS (
    table_name string COMMENT 'Aggregator type',
    key string COMMENT 'Key for Hbase',
    column_family string COMMENT 'Column family name for Hbase',
    column_name string COMMENT 'Column name for Hbase',
    data string COMMENT 'Json data from metric aggregates'
  )

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED;
```

Any ideas why this could happen would be of great help.

Comment: Maybe this SlideShare [deck](http://www.slideshare.net/StampedeCon/choosing-an-hdfs-data-storage-format-avro-vs-parquet-and-more-stampedecon-2015) could be useful to you

Comment: What is the point of using Hive in the first place, if all the processing is done in a "streaming" python jobs?? Remember that this "streaming" thing requires Hive to **deserialize** the input and **reserialize** it in TEXT format, then do the exact opposite with output.

Comment: Not sure that "embedded"  WHERE clause can be optimized for ORC (i.e. check stripe footers for min/max values, skip stripes that don't match WHERE clause anyway). So, with no predicate push-down and no vectorization, ORC does not have much added value. Possibly the reduced size on HDFS. But in your case the lower I/O does not make for the increased CPU cost...

Comment: 1) The point is that our analytics use hive for custom reports. We can write to hive and process separately and if i would not find the way to fix problems with ORC - we'll start moving this direction. 2) Where clause is used only for partitioning. dt = '2015-05-05' for example.

Comment: I don't expect ORC to speed up my transform queries, but i also didn't expect it to SLOW it x10